# .htaccess on heroku, angular2 app for gzip compression

Tags: .htaccess, heroku, angular-cli

Having an angular2 app on heroku, I would like to activate gzip compression. As outlined [here](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html), I add a .htaccess at the root of my project with the following

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
...
```

I compiled my app with `ng build --prod` so I have all the gz needed. I also put the .htaccess in the dist folder created by the build in the case it should be there. My app runs well but the gzip compression does not work (checked with [this link](https://varvy.com/tools/gzip/)).

Some of you have faced this issue before?

EDITED: Heroku does not accept .htaccess. To activate gzip compression, you only have to add the following lines to your `web.js`:

```
var compression = require(‘compression’);
app.use(compression());
```

Comment: Heroku does not accept .htaccess. To activate gzip, I only needed to add some lines in my web.js. Edited the post